# Why '@' salutation was not rendered

Tags: support, comments

I just posted a comment beginning with `@username`, and my `@username` part of the comment was not rendered (it was the first word in the comment). Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

If you post a comment under a user named "Smith" and you're writing "@Smith", the system won't auto-complete it, because you're obviously talking to the author of that answer/question.

If you want to direct it at someone else, it doesn't render it, either. It's not a bug.

The auto-fill will activate only when:

1. you're writing a comment at someone else other than the author;
2. that someone else already posted a comment under that question/answer (also if these were posted by you).

Comment: @Alenanno This is a test.

Answer (score 0):

The @-reference to a user is automatically removed in some cases, when that user is already notified of a comment.

For example, if Jasper Loy would have used *@Alenanno*, that would have been removed, because the comment was clearly for him, who is already notified.
In my comment, which is the second comment for that answer, the @-reference has not been removed because I could refer the comment to Jasper Loy, instead of Alenanno. To notice that both Alenanno and Jasper Loy should get a notification for my comment; for sure, Alenanno gets notified because I have commented the post he created.